# Angular 2 ngModel form knowing the new selections

Tags: forms, angular

Lets take this form:

```
<form name="setQuestions_form" (ngSubmit)="set_questions()">
    <ng-select [multiple]="true" [options]="questions" [(ngModel)]="selectedQuestions" name="selectedQuestions"></ng-select>
    <button>send</button>
</form>
```

selectedQuestions is an array of Questions:

```
selectedQuestions: Question[] = [];
```

The method set_questions sends the data to the backend:

```
this.questionService.create(this.selectedQuestions).subscribe();
```

So my DB the 1st time is empty but the 2nd time I already have saved questions (that could be customized with other functions so I dont want them to be deleted or changed), whats the way to insert in the DB only the new questions selected? There is anything in Angular 2 to know in a form the new options in a select or should I make the work in the backend comparing the saved questions with the new ones?

**Example:**

```
[ ] Question 1
[X] Question 2
[X] Question 3
[ ] Question 4

[ ] Question 1
[ ] Question 2
[X] Question 3
[X] Question 4
```

Here I want to know that the Question 2 has been removed, the Question 4 has been added, I dont care with the untouched ones so i can send to the backend something like this:

```
- Added: Question 4
- Removed: Question 2
```

Ignoring Question 1 and Question 3(that is already checked but is not a new one)

Comment: So in `questions`, you have questions from the previous user submits and you want to know when the user has selected new ones that are not already in the database?

Comment: users can add or remove questions from the select component, so i only want to know the new or the removed ones. I dont know if there is something in Angular 2 that simplifies this task

Comment: There is no Angular feature that could track them so you have to implement one. I will suggest you take a look at `ngOnChanges` event which is part of the Angular life cycle or adds `onChange` event to the `ng-select` and create logic what to happen when user select or unselect an option. You will need one more array to keep track of what person selected and what he unselected and then compare it with the one you got from the db.

Comment: May be the use of [md-checkbox](https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/api) event MdCheckboxChange may help.

Answer (score 0):

Here an example with md-checkbox, multi-select.html:

```
<div>
    <md-checkbox name="Q1" (change)="onCheckChange($event)">Question 1</md-checkbox>
    <md-checkbox name="Q2" (change)="onCheckChange($event)">Question 2</md-checkbox>
    <md-checkbox name="Q3" (change)="onCheckChange($event)">Question 3</md-checkbox>
    <md-checkbox name="Q4" (change)="onCheckChange($event)">Question 4</md-checkbox>
</div>
```

And here the component multi-select.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'multi-select',
    templateUrl: 'multi-select.html'
})

export class MultiSelect implements OnInit {
    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() { }

    onCheckChange($event) {
        //console.log($event);
        console.log($event.source.name,"=",$event.checked);
    }
}
```

Of cause there is a `import { MdCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material';` and an entry in the imports field in the according module.
The console.log is then:

```
Q4 = true
Q2 = false
```